# TensorFlow: Evaluate network that was trained with padded data with unpadded data (ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape...)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a `dynamic_rnn` network with input data of shape `(batch_size, sequence_lengh, depth)` that has been manually padded to the length of the longest example (in this case 97) and have saved it as a checkpoint.
To evaluate the network on "real world data" I load the checkpoint and feed unpadded data to the restored input tensor (using `tf.Session.run()`).  I receive a

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 32) for Tensor 'input_x:0', which has shape '(?, 97, 32)'
```

The input tensor was restored using `tf.Graph.get_operation_by_name()`.

A possible workaround would be to pad the input so it conforms to (?,97,32) but since support for batch padding (which intuitively should encounter the same problem) is implemented I'm hoping for pointers to a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence length for the inputs must be the same as for the training data.  The neural net was constructed to accept an array of a certain size.  In your case it is a sequence of length 97 with a length 32 encoding.

You can kind of think of it like a very rigid `numpy` function, that has hard-coded size restrictions on everything but the first dimension.  You should pad your input with the same padding that you used to pad your training data.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I got distracted by a post on [wildml](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features/) where it is stated that "[...] you only need to pad examples within the batch to the same length (the maximum length of examples in that batch). That way, a really long example will only affect a single batch [...]"